# Get HTTPS request header fields in an unmanaged exposed custom CDS entity in a RAP OData V2 service?

Tags: httprequest, abap, cds

My custom entity is exposed and implemented by an ABAP class (implementing interface if_rap_query_provider). I can get data via OData V2.

But the HTTP request header fields are hidden by the SAP framework so I can't use them in my `if_rap_query_provider~select` implementation. Is there a solution to get the request header fields in the implementing class?

I have to transfer additional data from client to server (besides the data model) that must be handled by our backend business logic.

Environment: ABAP 7.54 / 1909 / OnPremise

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Why dont you pass them? Might this help: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/13/set-and-get-custom-http-header/

Comment: If you can access this runtime object, you can get also these additional informations, but unfortunately this object is not available in the redefined if_rap_query_provider-select method.

Thanks for the comment.